# Scikit-learn Imputer reducing dimensions when using it twice

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dimension

I understand that: "When axis=0, columns which only contained missing values at fit are discarded upon transform."
So the first time I use the Imputer all NaN values are replaced by the mean and the columns only contained missing values are replaced.
My code:

```
df.shape
(1430,488)

#1. delete all columns containing 0
df=df.loc[:, (df != 0).any(axis=0)]
df.shape
(1430,370)

#2. replace all Nan Values with mean
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imr = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
imr = imr.fit(df)
imputed_data = imr.transform(df.values)
imputed_data.shape
(1430,321)

#3. replace all 0 Values with mean
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imr = Imputer(missing_values=0, strategy='mean', axis=0)
imr = imr.fit(df)
imputed_data = imr.transform(df.values)
imputed_data.shape
(1430,167)
```

So in the first step i am deleting all columns containing 0 and then in step 2 the imputer is deleting all columns with only NaN. But why is there a reduction of dimension when it comes to step 3 to 167 columns? I already deleted all columns with only 0 in step 1?

Another question is how can i transform the new numpy array back to pandas without losing the header?

Thank you,
R

Comment: Keeping the columns names should be as easy as just passing df instead of df.values.  ( imputed_data = imr.transform(df) ). Are you sure that df=df.loc[:, (df != 0).any(axis=0)]
 is doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: if i use df instead of df.values the column names are gone too. Is there any form to keep them?